# How to add Blackberry Torch 9860 emulator in eclipse 3.7.2?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have made an application for **BB os 7** and earlier. When I run my app on emulator by default it is running on **BB bold 9900**. I have added multiple resolution suupport and want to test my app on BB torch 9860 for 480 x 800 resolution. I cant find any option to switch the emulator. I am using **BB JRE 7.1** and have tried in

> Run -> Run Configurations -> Simulator tab

but it is not listed there also.
Thanks

Comment: The 9860 emulator does not come with the BlackBerry Eclipse plugin.  You have to download it and install it separately, and then you'll see it available.  [Try visiting this link](http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/resources/simulators.html) (toward the bottom of the page), which may be redirected if you're not in the US.

Comment: download from this link - https://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/contactFormPreload.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477&dl=08F4EF46B10FB47911B22A6FEE238368

Comment: if you already have the emulator, then go to your - run configuration, then under simulator tab, change the simulator.